# Running appium with python and seeing this --> RangeError: Port should be > 0 and < 65536

Tags: appium, python-appium

Running appium with python and seeing this --> ADB not able to talk to device giving RangeError: Port should be > 0 and < 65536

Answer (score 0):

This happened because in order to run Appium.app (which is mac UI app from Appium) I updated the node_modules. In order to fix this you need to uninstall node & appium with all the node_modules removed and then reinstall everything.

Not able to dig down which node module component was causing problem but adb.js was the one to give out error.

In order to get help in removing node visit this very helpful post --> http://benznext.com/completely-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-os-x/

In addition to this if somebody is seeing python egg six based version conflicts for appium then make sure to delete your venv under your test root dir and then make it again and then update the six using `easy_install six`.

After this delete all the pycache files and relaunch appium and virtualenv wrapper to start testing again.